# How do I remove rows based on multiple conditions in Python / Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table which looks something like this:

| Identified | Software | Version | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Microsoft Office | 2 | 2022-05-25 |
| 0 | Microsoft Office | 1 | 2022-03-21 |
| 0 | Adobe Photoshop | 2 | 2022-04-20 |
| 1 | Adobe Photoshop | 1 | 2021-04-04 |

The 'Identified' column is a column I have created using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

dfcheck = pd.read_csv('version-data.csv', encoding='utf8')
df = pd.DataFrame(dfcheck)

olderdata = dt.date.today() - pd.DateOffset(years=1)

df['Identified'] = (df['Date'] <= olderdata).astype(int)
```

In this I have marked everything older than one year.  So now what I'm trying to do is create a new dataframe which shows all software packages which have been identified.  Here is the output I am looking for:

| Identified | Software | Version | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Adobe Photoshop | 2 | 2022-04-20 |
| 1 | Adobe Photoshop | 1 | 2021-04-04 |

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
out = df.groupby('Software').filter(lambda x: (x.Identified==1).any())

print (out)

   Identified          Software   Version        Date
2           0   Adobe Photoshop         2  2022-04-20
3           1   Adobe Photoshop         1  2021-04-04
```